# SQL Server - Can't See 2 tables in Query Design View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a weird problem here.  If I right-click and click 'Design Query in Editor' I can see 9 of my 11 tables.  I would expect to see all 11 tables in this query design view.  I don't know why there would be any difference between 2 tables and the other 9, but something is preventing the query design view from working correctly.  There must be some reason for this, like rights or permissions, or something like that.  I have full rights for the whole database.  Would could be preventing this from working?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all the tables in the same database?

Comment: have you tried refreshing the object explorer?

Comment: Yes, to both questions.  Maybe there is some kind of permissions setting on these tables.  Not sure.  

I loaded all 11 data sets the same way; I used a script and changed only the table name and path:
SELECT * INTO tbl_Facilities
FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\State Street\Final Deliverables\Raw Data\Facilities.xlsx',
       'SELECT * FROM [Facilities$]')

That shouldn't have any impact at all.  I don't get it.

Comment: Ah!  Now, all of a sudden, it's working.  I don't know what changed here.  Maybe something just got refreshed, but I have no idea what.  Sorry to waste people's time.